# Security implications in dynamically rendering views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

There is a requirement for the ASP.NET MVC website I am building, that states the administrator needs to be able to create a cshtml file manually in the file system (under Views folder of course), and then able to access that page through a controller action. (i.e. create file called `Test.cshtml`, then access via `/Content/Test`)

I've done this via the following approach:

First, a custom route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "StandardContent", // my controller
            url: "Content/{pageName}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Content", action = "Render", pageName = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

And then the controller action that takes the view name as the parameter, checks whether the requested view name exists then renders the view:

```
public ActionResult Render(string pageName)
{
    if (pageName.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    // if no view exists with this name, go 404
    if (!this.ViewExists(pageName)) // my extension method for view checking
    {
        return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Error");
    }

    return View(pageName);
}
```

This works perfectly well and I am happy with it, except for its security implications. Here I'm basically taking whatever **raw input** the user writes in the url, and checking if a view exists with that input. Could the user possibly write some **malicious parameters** that might allow them to access a file that should normally be **restricted** access (e.g. a connection string file)? And if so, how should I prevent it?

---

Here's the code for the extension method `this.ViewExists(pageName)` if it helps.

```
public static bool ViewExists(this Controller controller, string viewName)
{
    var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, null);
    return result.View != null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same functionality in my application and simply added a regular expression check to sleep better.
You can simply add it to your `ViewExists` method:

```
public static bool ViewExists(this Controller controller, string viewName)
{
    // check for viewName null or empty here?

    if (!Regex.IsMatch(viewName, "^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$"))
        throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");

    var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, null);
    return result.View != null;
}
```

Make sure to use only allowed symbols (letters, digits and underscore (_) in my case) in your view file names.

---

As for me, I incapsulated this method into base controller class:

```
public class BaseController : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult DynamicView(string viewName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pageName))
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(viewName, "^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$"))
            return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Error");

        var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, null);
        if (result.View == null)
            return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Error");

        return View(viewName);
    }
}
```

Then, if you inherit all controller from this `BaseController`, you can use this one-liner whenever you need:

```
public ActionResult Render(string pageName)
{
    return DynamicView(pageName); // short, simple and reusable
}
```

`BaseController` is convenient thing in general and can incapsulate many useful MVC logics.